# Facebook shows "app name" as post author

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm posting on facebook using official PHP SDK.
I've created an app called "Istacron" and I setup all tokens.

Little code snippet:

```
$fb = new Facebook([
  'app_id' => $clientId,
  'app_secret' => $clientSecret,
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
]);

$meta['source' => $fb->fileToUpload($filePath)];
$response = $fb('/me/photos', $meta, $accessToken);
```

Where $accessToken is my personal profile "user access token".

The problem is Facebook display "Istacron" (app name) as author, instead of my name.

[image]

Comment: _"The problem is Facebook display "Istacron" (app name) as author, instead of my name."_ - no, it doesn’t - it shows "Roberta" as the author/owner of the post. What you are referring to, is called the _app attribution_. This is shown for all posts made to user profiles, so that people will know where the content came from (either because they like it so much, that they want to become a user of your app as well, or because they are so annoyed by what your app posts that they want to know what app to report.)

Comment: no, "Roberta" is the name of my facebook page

Comment: If you posted _as_ the page, then you did not use a user access token, I presume, but actually a page access token. But this notice is only shown to page admins in the first place, normal page visitors will never get to see that.